# Creating Nuget Package containing static classses

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, nuget-package

I'm trying to create a nuget package for a project called IdentityUtility to use in other projects.
The problem is that any projects that I add the nuget package to cannot see the static classes in the nuget package (the classes contain extension methods).
Everything else is visible. 
I've tried just referencing the IdentityUtility project without packing it and everything works perfectly.

Is there some settings I need to change when creating a nuget package when my project has static classes?

Here is one of the static classes

```
 using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
 using System;

 namespace IdentityUtility
 {
public static class IdentityUtilityExtensions
{

    /// <summary>
    /// Set up Identity Utility for use in app.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="services"></param>
    /// <param name="setupOptions">Specific setup details</param>
    /// <returns>IServiceCollection with IdentityUtility attached</returns>
    public static IServiceCollection AddIdentityUtility(this IServiceCollection services, IdentitySetupOptions setupOptions)
    {
        if (services == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(services));


        if (setupOptions == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(setupOptions));

        if (setupOptions.IdentityServerUrl != null)
            IdentitySettings.LOGICORE_IDENTITY_URL = setupOptions.IdentityServerUrl;
        if (setupOptions.RequestingService != null)
            IdentitySettings.THIS_SERVICE = setupOptions.RequestingService;
        if (setupOptions.EmailConfirmedReturnUrl != null)
            IdentitySettings.EMAIL_CONFIRMED_RETURN_URL = setupOptions.EmailConfirmedReturnUrl;
        if (setupOptions.TokenPrivateKey != null)
            IdentitySettings.TOKEN_PRIVATE_KEY = setupOptions.TokenPrivateKey;
        if (setupOptions.TokenExpirationMinutes != 0)
            IdentitySettings.TOKEN_EXPIRATION_MINUTES = setupOptions.TokenExpirationMinutes;
        if (setupOptions.CookieExpirationMinutes != 0)
            IdentitySettings.COOKIE_EXPIRATION_MINUTES = setupOptions.CookieExpirationMinutes;

        services.AddIdentityPolicies();

        return services;
    }//AddIdentityUtility
 }//Cls
}//NS
```

When I try to call the extension method with

```
   services.AddIdentityUtility(setupOptions);
```

I get an error saying that IServiceCollection does not contain a definition for AddIdentityUtility etc.

This problem goes away when I reference the project in the normal way without creating a Nuget package

Comment: Are the static classes public? Are the extension methods on them public? Have you got a `using Namespace.Containing.Extension.Methods`? It would be really helpful if you could share some of your code (maybe even an [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) so that we can assist you better :)

Comment: But to answer your question - no, there is no nuget-specific setting that you need to set. You can easily demonstrate this to yourself - add the library as a normal project reference from disk, and you should find you are still unable to see your static classes and extension methods, as something is wrong in your project.

Comment: When I add the library as a normal project it works fine.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the code - don't write it as a comment...

Comment: If it works when you add it as a normal project reference *and* other classes in that library are visible when added through NuGet then I'm not sure of the problem. If other classes in that library weren't visible, then I would be suggesting to check the project reference (e.g. to check it didn't target a newer version of .NET Framework than the project it had been installed in, or to ensure that it was definitely in the NuGet package).

Comment: How can you tell if it's DEFINITELY in the nuget package?

Comment: Because it works if you add an assembly reference. Extract the .nupkg and inspect the assembly. There's nothing special about NuGet packages, it's just a convenient way to ship and reference assemblies. Chances are your package contains an old assembly (with a different namespace or a non-public class), or no assembly at all. That is, of course, assuming you have the `using IdentityUtility` directive present.

Comment: Well, if you can access other classes that are in the same DLL (which you said you could?) then it is definitely in the nuget package and is correctly being referenced. However, if you are not sure, check your project references. If the library is not there, or has a yellow warning triangle, then you know there is a problem.

Comment: @CodeCaster Yes, that's a really good idea - verify that the dll in the nuget package has the method you expect it to by unzipping the .nupkg, and opening the dll in IlSpy, dotpeek, or similar. You might just have an old version in there.

Comment: @RB. & CodeCaster Thanks for your help. I repackaged everything this morning and the new packages work. I honestly have no idea what the difference was.

Comment: @Shanie You were almost certainly packaging an old version - I do stuff like that all the time! Typical scenario is you are doing a release build, but getting the nuget package from the debug folder...

Answer (score 0):

While it seems like for you it was the fact that you were referencing an old package, for me, I had to make sure my using statement was as follows:

```
using static NugetPackageNamespace.Extension
```

...that did the trick!

Comment: Note: From C# 6.0 and upward